# Getting this error in command.Parameters.Add("_trdate", Format(dteDate, "yyyy-MM-dd"))

Tags: vb.net, function, postgresql, componentone

```
  command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            command.CommandText = "{?=call gtab09_INSERT(_acyrid,_RepId,_DrId,_vrid,_mode, _trno, _trdate, _acid, _vrno, _SuppId,_custname,_netamt,_disrate,_disamt,_RoundOff,_jrmid, _userid,_userdtm,_VSNo,_RecdAmt,_cstrate,_cstsaleamt,_cstamt,_tdrate,_tdamt,_cdrate,_cdamt,_CessRate,_CessAmt,_odesc1,_oamt1,_CashCredit,_OrderNo,_OrderDate,_CustAdd2,_Remarks,_WhoRetSl,_PatName,_DrName,_FormId,_SalesMan,_CFMode,_PatId,_StkPtId,_DisType,_BranchID)}"
            command.Parameters.Add("_acyrid", gintAcYrId)
            command.Parameters.Add("_RepId", Val(cboRep.SelectedValue))
            command.Parameters.Add("_DrId", Val(cboDoctor.SelectedValue))
            command.Parameters.Add("_vrid", mlngVrId)
            command.Parameters.Add("_mode", Val(cboMode.SelectedIndex))
            command.Parameters.Add("_trno", txtslno.Text)
            command.Parameters.Add("_trdate", Format(dteDate, "yyyy-MM-dd"))
            command.Parameters.Add("_acid", CustAcId)
```

I am getting

```
Unable to cast object of type 
'C1.Win.C1Input.C1DateEdit' to type 'System.IConvertible' error
```

in

```
command.Parameters.Add("_trdate", Format(dteDate, "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

using `VB.net 2008` and `PostgreSql` Database in `postgres` date field should be in `yyyy-MM-dd` Format. This is an Insert function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is trying to convert `C1DateEdit` control to a formatted string which is not valid operation. I guess you want to convert `DateTime` value from that control instead :

```
command.Parameters.Add("_trdate", Format(dteDate.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

assuming that `dteDate.Value` is a correct way to get `DateTime` value from `C1DateEdit`, since I've never used ComponentOne control in my life. Anyway, if `_trdate` parameter expect a `DateTime` type in postgres, you can just pass a `DateTime` object as parameter value. No need to take care of formatting, it will be handled automatically. Something like this (*same assumption applied*) :

```
command.Parameters.Add("_trdate", dteDate.Value)
```

Hope this shed some lights to your problem.

Comment: please [accept this answer to confirm this is solution to your problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). If this doesn't solve the problem please state so, hence people with the same problem won't try non-working answer, or at least know what is lacking from this answer/in what way it doesn't work. Thank you.